# Load three UITableViews from different datasources

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, datasource

I have three uiTableViews on a view.

I have created three different NSMutableArray loaded with different data.

I need to place one of the NSMutableArray as the datasource for one of the UITableView.

I am able to assign all three UITableViews datasource through the viewDidLoad of the form.

But what I really need to do, is assign each of the UITableView datasource to a different NSMutableArray.

How can I perform this task?

thanks
tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all three UITableViews share the same datasource object (the object that holds all three of your arrays), then just use if statements to differentiate between the table views asking for the data:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // If table 1 is asking, give it table 1 data...
    if (tableView == myTableView1)
    {
        // Assume all sections have 3 rows each for
        // purposes of simple demonstration...
        return [dataSourceForTable1 count];
    }

    // If table 2 is asking, give it table 2 data...
    if (tableView == myTableView2)
    {
        // Assume all sections have 3 rows each for
        // purposes of simple demonstration...
        return [dataSourceForTable2 count];
    }

    // If table 3 is asking, give it table 3 data...
    if (tableView == myTableView3)
    {
        // Assume all sections have 3 rows each for
        // purposes of simple demonstration...
        return [dataSourceForTable3 count];
    }

   // The compiler will complain if we don't have
   // a final return since it's possible none of the 
   // if statements will be true ...
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry - this does not make sense to me.  What goes in the ...  currently i only have  return [listOfLocations count]; in the method.  I need to have a different dataset per each tableview.

Comment: You should give the related documentation a thorough read. Table views can share a data source. When each asks for specific information (like the number of rows in a section) your answer depends on the table that asked for it. I'll update the code to give an example.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath